# MongooseError [MissingSchemaError]: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Comments"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using sucrase on my project. When I try to access the show route, only prints the data from Campground model without any comments, causing this error.

My show.ejs:

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>

<h1><%= campground.name %></h1>

<img src="<%= campground.image %> " />

<p><%= campground.description %></p>

<% campground.comments.forEach(comment => { %>
<p><strong><%= comment.author %></strong> - <%= comment.text %></p>
<% }) %> <%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

My app.js header:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Campground from "./models/campground";
import seedDB from "./seeds";

seedDB();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelpCamp", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("assets"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

My campground.js:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

//* schema
const campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  image: String,
  description: String,
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comments",
    },
  ],
});

export default mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

comment.js:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  author: String,
});

export default mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

My show route:

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", (req, res) => {
  Campground.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate("comments")
    .exec((err, foundCampground) =>
      err
        ? console.log(err)
        : res.render("show", { campground: foundCampground })
    );
});
```

Why I'm getting this schema error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your model before you use it so require your model first in app.js as you imported campground model

```
require('./models/Comment'); // import Comment from "./models/comment";
```

Or there might be issue with Model name you are using in campground.js:

```
{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "Comments", // USE "Comment"
},
```

Comment: I didn't need to import the model, only rename the ref and it worked. But why?

Comment: Oh, I understand it. I created a model with name "Comment", so, in the ref, was trying to access a model with name "Comments", that does not exist.